# Single word for a sidelined or late soccer player?

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

I am looking for a single word that describes an instance where a soccer player is either late for a match, injured, or deemed unable to play for some span of time.

In all instances, the player may eventually be able to join the match.

The meaning of the word should convey that the player is not necessarily out of the match for good.

I considered 'inactive' and 'unavailable', but they sound more permanent.

'Sidelined' may be okay, but I'm not sure it conveys a meaning of being late for a match.

Comment: to be out of action temporarily. There is no single word. What's with the single word thing, anyway?

Comment: It's for a software application on a phone with limited screen space

Comment: 'Out of action'.  That may work.

Comment: Yes, and you could shorten it to: OOA :)

Comment: 'Unavailable' is the usual term.

Comment: Pinch hitter, deploy from the bench, substitute, sub in (verb), reinforcement.  I'm not sure a player is allowed to sub in if he's not there at the beginning of the match.

Comment: @Edwin, I think you're correct.  Unavailable works, it isn't as I thought to mean a permanent state.

Comment: pinch hitter is for baseball not football (soccer).

Comment: unavailable sounds like a product to me. Not like football (soccer). Even absent is better. There are many reasons a player might be absent.

Comment: @Lambie, Absent to me sounds more permanent, not like someone would be available to play later in the game.

Comment: What about simply "OUT"?

Comment: "Not  playing" also would work. Actually, you can take a look on English sites, absent  is used. I think he means absent from a game due to lateness, injury, illness or force majeure.

Answer (score 0):

"Benched" may be what you're looking for. From Merriam-Webster:

> 2 a : to seat on a bench
>
> b (1) : to remove from or keep out of a game;
>
> (2) : to remove from the starting lineup

E.g., The player was benched for missing team meetings.

Comment: If the player is late, I don't think it could be said that they are benched.

Comment: If you mean that the game has started and the coach wants to put in Jake but Jake hasn't shown up yet, then no, "benched" would not apply. But once Jake shows up, the coach may bench him as punishment for being late; I thought that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Late, injured or unable to play is not benched necessarily.

Comment: @Lambie, I agree. I think the best terms were already mentioned in the question. I merely brought up another possibility since those had apparently been rejected.

Comment: Do you have any references to *benched* players being fielded later in the *same* game as the 2b(2) entry seems to allow? This is otherwise a good answer.